# Sabre Unable to use "Revalidate Itinerary" V4 API

Tags: sabre, sabredav

I'm getting below error from Revalidate Itinerary API.

```
{
  "status": "Incomplete",
  "type": "Application",
  "errorCode": "ERR.2SG.SERVICE_VERSION_DEPRECATED",
  "timeStamp": "2024-03-26T12:21:06.387Z",
  "message": "Requested service STPS_SHOPFLIGHTSREVALIDATEAPI version v4.3.0 is deprecated"
}
```

I did try to upgrade the version 5 but getting different response as compare to previously .